# How do we make Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio behave in a More Prompt Manner?

Tags: sql-server, output, ssms, prompt

Lets say you do a execute a group of insert or updates in your SQL code.

IF all runs well then you get a bunch of statements like the following:

(1 row(s) affected)

(0 row(s) affected)

(5 row(s) affected)

(2 row(s) affected)

(3 row(s) affected)

How can you make the above more verbose?  How can you configure how verbose the output from within the SQL code itself?

Comment: What kind of output are you looking for?

Comment: `DECLARE @rc int; UPDATE F SET Col1 = 'X' FROM dbo.FOO AS F; SET @rc = @@ROWCOUNT; PRINT 'Today, we updated ' + CAST(@rc AS varchar(10)) + ' rows. Please have a most lovely day'`

Comment: You could also restructure your SQL to make use of the [OUTPUT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms177564.aspx) clause, but that is most certainly not just a configuration thing.

Comment: The "bunch of statements" could be avoided if you'd use SET NOCOUNT ON before your SQL statements. The output you're looking for can be customized (= coded) using the OUTPUT clause, the PRINT statement or even RAISERROR statements. That's all up to you...

Comment: @Lmu92 Wouldn't setting nocount make the output less verbose/more terse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than the number of rows affected by a query, you can also display the the steps that your database server actually performed to execute your query. This is often called the "execution plan". In SQL Server Management Studio, you can select the **Include Actual Execution Plan (Ctrl+M)** option prior to executing your query. Following execution you can view details describing how SQL Server executed your query by looking at the **Execution plan** tab. In Oracle, which I am less familiar with, there is a similar capability implemented by the EXPLAIN PLAN statement.